# how to handle with different size of images in CNN network

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I am doing images to fit the puzzle and to identifying perfect pairs. 
here my data

```
solution.head()
id  pair
0   1   686
1   2   540
2   3   971
3   4   910
4   5   616
```

I have a images shapes like these:

```
    png = []
    for image_path in glob.glob("training/training/*.png"):
        png.append(misc.imread(image_path))    

    im = np.asarray(png)

    print ('Importing done...', im.shape)

Importing done... (1000,)

array([array([[[247, 255, 102],
        [247, 255, 102],
        [247, 255, 102],
        ...,
        [247, 255, 102],
        [247, 255, 102],
        [247, 255, 102]],

       [[247, 255, 102],
        [247, 255, 102],
        [247, 255, 102],
        ...,
        [247, 255, 102],
        [247, 255, 102],
        [247, 255, 102]],

       [[247, 255, 102],
        [247, 255, 102],
        [247, 255, 102],
        ...,
        [247, 255, 102],
        [247, 255, 102],
        [247, 255, 102]],

       ...,

       [[247, 255, 102],
        [247, 255, 102],
        [247, 255, 102],
        ...,
        [247, 255, 102],
        [247, 255, 102],
        [247, 255, 102]],

       [[247, 255, 102],
        [247, 255, 102],
        [247, 255, 102],
        ...,
        [247, 255, 102],
        [247, 255, 102],
        [247, 255, 102]],

       [[247, 255, 102],
        [247, 255, 102],
        [247, 255, 102],
        ...,
        [247, 255, 102],
        [247, 255, 102],
        [247, 255, 102]]], dtype=uint8),
       array([[[165, 255, 102],
        [165, 255, 102],
        [165, 255, 102],
        ...,
        [165, 255, 102],
        [165, 255, 102],
        [165, 255, 102]],

       [[165, 255, 102],
        [165, 255, 102],
        [165, 255, 102],
        ...,
        [165, 255, 102],
        [165, 255, 102],
        [165, 255, 102]],

       [[165, 255, 102],
        [165, 255, 102],
        [165, 255, 102],
        ...,
        [165, 255, 102],
        [165, 255, 102],
        [165, 255, 102]],

       ...,

       [[165, 255, 102],
        [165, 255, 102],
        [165, 255, 102],
        ...,
```

I didn't understand how to find the  perfect pairs images. I am trying to resize them  and converting to gray , but its getting error. please help me to find  the images to fit together in pairs.
here my colab link :
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1bCQUHrXNjdWX8-WKSq6LK01XpR4D52J_

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code:

```
   import numpy as np
    import cv2
    import os
    df=pd.read_csv(os.path.join(file_path,'solution.csv'))
    training_data = []
    IMG_SIZE = 100
    for img in  os.listdir('training/training') :  
      path = 'training/training/'+img
      id = img.split('.')[0]
      img = cv2.imread(path,1)
      img = cv2.resize(img, (IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE),3)     
      img = np.array(img)
      target = df['pair][int(id)]
      training_data.append([img ,target  ])
```

Comment: Thank you amara , here getting some error on target variable your given quotes on pair variable.how to solve that, when  I am given the only pair variable to quotes to

Comment: target = df['pair'][int(id)]

Comment: I have one doubt about these, the pairs having 500, but images having 1000, how could I build a Cnn network. please give me some demo about these.

Comment: in the csv file  , are the 'id' column mean the names of images ?

Comment: hi Amara, my images are  png types,  you  have provided code is I executed, but  its getting some  error .keyerror: 867,

Comment: how  should i join to image with their ids , The ids are 500, but images 1000 . please  help amara how to build CNN network , I am trying build a  cnn network using U-net, 
 and  also i am   applyed  to_categorical for pairs ,but it showing image shapes 1000, apirs got 500.